How to disable showing drawerContent on swipe at the top right corner inside a Drawer.Screen
I am using a drawer navigator of @react-navigation/drawer.I have added drawer content too. The header of it is not visible by default.
<Drawer.Navigator 
  screenOptions={{headerShown: false, drawerPosition: 'right'}} 
  drawerContent={MYCUSTOM_COMPONENT}>
    <Drawer.Screen component={SAMPLE_SCREEN}/>
</Drawer.Navigator>

SAMPLE_SCREEN has some content. When the user swipes at the top right corner of this screen, the drawer content is popping out. Is there any option available at SAMPLE_SCREEN to stop this default behavior?

Adding swipeEnabled option at the screen level resolved the issue. This option is available at the Navigator level too. It will disable the swipe on all screens.
<Drawer.Navigator 
  screenOptions={{headerShown: false, drawerPosition: 'right'}} 
  drawerContent={MYCUSTOM_COMPONENT}>
    <Drawer.Screen component={SAMPLE_SCREEN} options={{ swipeEnabled: false }}/>
</Drawer.Navigator>

